# IOS Help Modifying Code Snippet

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

I am using a view controller that consists of a horizontal scroll view and page controller to display a number of images in a carrousel fashion.  The controller is passed an array of images and displays them starting with the first image.  I obtained the code snippet from a third party tutorial and have spent the last day trying to understand it and change its functionality.  I have been trying to make the carrousel start at the middle of the array of images, (i.e. if there are nine images start at image five and allow for scrolling both ways) but have had no luck in modifying the existing code.  I have played around with the loadPage and loadVisiblePages methods but have had little luck.  Here are the .m and .h files.

PeekPagedScrollViewController.m

```
#import "PeekPagedScrollViewController.h"

@interface PeekPagedScrollViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pageViews;

- (void)loadVisiblePages;
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page;
- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page;
@end

@implementation PeekPagedScrollViewController

@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
@synthesize pageControl = _pageControl;
@synthesize gallaryType = _gallaryType;
@synthesize pageImages = _pageImages;
@synthesize pageViews = _pageViews;
@synthesize startPoint = _startPoint;

#pragma mark -

- (void)loadVisiblePages
{
    // First, determine which page is currently visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));

    // Work out which pages we want to load
    NSInteger firstPage = page - 1;
    NSInteger lastPage = page + 1;

    // Purge anything before the first page
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<firstPage; i++) {
        [self purgePage:i];
    }
    for (NSInteger i=firstPage; i<=lastPage; i++) {
        [self loadPage:i];
    }
    for (NSInteger i=lastPage+1; i<self.pageImages.count; i++) {
        [self purgePage:i];
    }
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page
{
    if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count)
    {
        // If it's outside the range of what we have to display, then do nothing
        return;
    }

    // Load an individual page, first seeing if we've already loaded it
    UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];

    if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null])
    {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0.0f;
        frame = CGRectInset(frame, 10.0f, 0.0f);

        UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page]];
        newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        newPageView.frame = frame;

        [self addTapHandler:newPageView actionSelector:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
        [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
    }


}

- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page
{
    if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count)
    {
        // If it's outside the range of what we have to display, then do nothing
        return;
    }

    // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
    UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull*)pageView != [NSNull null])
    {
        [pageView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}

- (void)addTapHandler:(UIView *)pageView actionSelector:(SEL)actionSelector
{
    [pageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:actionSelector];
    [pageView addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (_gallaryType == 0)
    {
        NSString *messageString = @"Use as profile image?";
        UIAlertView *imageAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Image" message:messageString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [imageAlertView show];

    }
    else if (_gallaryType == 1)
    {
        NSString *messageString = @"Use as cover photo?";
        UIAlertView *imageAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Image" message:messageString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [imageAlertView show];

    }
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // add yes button text here 
    }
}

#pragma mark -

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

    self.title = @"Paged";

    NSInteger pageCount = self.pageImages.count;

    // Set up the array to hold the views for each page
    self.pageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i)
    {
        [self.pageViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Set up the content size of the scroll view
    CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * self.pageImages.count, pagesScrollViewSize.height);

    // Load the initial set of pages that are on screen
    [self loadVisiblePages];
}

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.scrollView = nil;
    self.pageControl = nil;
    self.pageImages = nil;
    self.pageViews = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Load the pages which are now on screen
    [self loadVisiblePages];
}

@end
```

PeekPagedScrollViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PeekPagedScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pageImages;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *gallaryType;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *startPoint;

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just take scroll view 
set its content size/// that is how much it is going to scroll

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width*imageArray.count,scrollView.frame.size.height);

// and then set the starting point

scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(currentpage * scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);

Comment: thanks man overflow is always such a good help @alpha

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to scroll to a particular page. The rest of the thing will automatically happens. Try like this

```
CGRect frame  = self.scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = (frame.size.width * page);        
frame.origin.y = 0;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

Here page is the page number(eg 5)